# ansible playbook not able to find the inventory file

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am running an ansible playbook, in the playbook only I am calling a python script which actually generates the inventory file which needs to be used by this playbook.. 
For the very first execution, although the playbook runs fine but it does not perform any listed operation on those target servers as it does not able to find the inventory file..

It provide this info:

```
ansible-playbook play.yml -i /home/inventory.txt
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/inventory.txt as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

For the second time of playbook run, it runs fine and perform all the listed operations on the target servers.
Is it possible that the ansible could use the inventory file which is being generated by the python file..

Comment: Can you share at least your `/home/inventory.txt` and maybe also `play.yml`? Otherwise, how should one be able to answer here?

Comment: Sounds like you could use the python script not in the playbook but as a [dynamic inventory file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#using-inventory-directories-and-multiple-inventory-sources) - if you pass a `.py` file as an inventory, it will be executed and the output used as the inventory